# Highcharts Column Range - How to render series data stored in PHP variables?

Tags: php, highcharts

I have problems when trying to render correctly the Highcharts column range table. I have all the necessary data stored in PHP variables. The problem is that I can't get the table rendered when passing this variables.
If I try to pass direct numeric data, then the table is rendered, so the issue is in the `data` field.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
if (!isset($divId)) {
    $mt = microtime();
    $mt = explode(" ", $mt);
    $divId = "stacked_container_" . floor($mt[0] * 100000) . "_" . $mt[1];
}
?>
<div id="<?php echo $divId; ?>" class="col-mx-12"></div>

<?php
$title = $elements['title'];
$resources = $elements['series']['resources'];
$values = $elements['series']['values'];

$resourcesSeries = '';
$valuesMinSeries = '';
$valuesMaxSeries = '';
foreach ($resources as $key => $resource) {
    $resourcesSeries .= '"' . $resource . '",';
    $valuesMinSeries .=  $values[$key][0] . ',';
    $valuesMaxSeries .=  $values[$key][1] . ',';
}

$globalNav = $view['nav'];

// Transforming strings into array type
$valuesMin = str_split($valuesMinSeries);
$valuesMax = str_split($valuesMaxSeries);

$globalNav->addScriptJS("
        $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#" . $divId . "').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'columnrange'
        },
        title: {
            text: '" . $title . "'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [" . $resourcesSeries . "]
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'range'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [ 
                    [<?php echo $valuesMin[0]?> , <?php echo $valuesMax[0]?> ]
                   ]
            }]
        });

    });
    ");

?>
```

In this example I'm trying to display only the first element of `$valuesMin` and `$valuesMax`.
The final aim is to render all the data, so I need to implement a `foreach` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to the problem. This is how:

```
    //The result will be in the $data variable
    $data = '';
    foreach ($resources as $key => $resource) {
    $resourcesSeries .= '"' . $resource . '",';
    $valuesMinSeries .=  $values[$key][0] . ',';
    $valuesMaxSeries .=  $values[$key][1] . ',';
    $data .= "[".values[$key][0]. "," .$values[$key][1]. "],";
    }
```

And in the `series` field:

```
series: [{
        data: [ " .$data. " ]
        }]
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be duplicating your `resources` array, by calling it as both your `$resources` variable, and your `$values` variable:

```
$resources = $elements['series']['resources'];
$values = $elements['series']['resources'];
```

Which I will assume should be something like:

```
$resources = $elements['series']['resources'];
$values = $elements['series']['values'];
```